# Will my approvals be deleted if I click on "End this workflow" in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: workflow

My workflow has completed and is approved however the first approver keeps getting notifications that his task is overdue. I can see he completed his task.  I want to stop the workflow but not delete the completed workflow history. When I click on "End this workflow" I get a message that says, "This will delete any previously created tasks".  There are no pending tasks so I'm afraid this will delete the completed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

that would delete the tasks, but not the workflow history

the workflow tasks is a separate list that contains the required approvals

but any workflow history log linked to the tasks will be removed

the best practice to avoid this problem is to add "log" actions during the workflow execution for the next workflows